# DNN Containers

Tags: containers, dotnetnuke

This might be a general question, but I can't seem to figure it out. What are containers in DNN? Skins are essentially a layout plus a colour scheme for the whole portal. So are containers the skin for desktopmodules?

Sorry if this question is novice. I am not confident in DNN yet, and am reading the doco. However i need this answer quite quickly.

Cheers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Containers allow you to add style and markup to any module independently of the page skin or the particular module.

The layout goes like this:

1. Default.aspx
2. Skin (.ascx control, either the
   Portal default or selected on the
       given tab) - this has panels on it
3. Container (.ascx control, this can allow you position some edit
       buttons and have a configurable wrapper around any module)
4. Module (.ascx control, usually coming from /DesktopModules)

I hope this helps,
-Eric

Answer (score 3):

Yes, container is like a skin for single module. Using one skin for entire page, and several skins (container skins) for modules you can quicker create expected appearance.

In general this is a simple html snippet with several placeholders.