# DotNetNuke: Skin vs Container vs Module

Tags: dotnetnuke

I've learned from [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042187/dnn-containers) question that Skins, Containers and Modules are ASCX files but they weren't explained well. What are the differences of the these ASCX files?

Answer (score 3):

Containers are "styling" for modules, but mainly just think of them as a Wrapper.

Modules provide Content and Functionality on your DNN website. The simplest way to think of a container, is to draw a box around the Content/Functionality in a module, that is your container.

If you notice the "careers 2.0" section of Stack Overflow on the right side of this page, the Careers 2.0" area at the top would be the module's title, while the list of jobs inside of that box would be the content provided by the module itself.

The skin provides the layout for a page.  It will have sections to which modules can be added, called panes (e.g. ContentPane, LeftPane, HeaderPane, etc.).

Skins and containers are design elements, whereas modules provide functionality.

Comment: So what about Site Containers?

Comment: A site Container is the default container to be used on all Pages. You can override that at the page level, choosing a default container for a page, which can also be overwritten at the Module level.

Comment: So technically we can use the same container in all three places?